# Labels with different colors (Blogger)

Tags: customization, blogger

I want that each label in Blogger have a different color. I tried to create a class to each label, for example, add a class ".Movies" to label Movies and class named ".News" to label News. But I don't know what to do next.

Here's my current code that affects all labels:

```
<div class='tl-label-post'><div class='postags'>
                  <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
                  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
                      <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a>
                      <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'/>
                    </b:loop>
                   </b:if>
                </div> </div></div>
```

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already dit it!

Keep the default CSS and HTML code of labels intact, and instead of changing it, do this for each label:

```
a[href^="http://www.YOURSITE.com/search/label/CINEMA"] {
color: #colorcode !important;
background: #colorcode !important;
}
```

You can see I've added the entire label path for Cinema. Similarly,
take full path of all labels and add different color rules for each
label

For example, let's say one more label name is 'Television'.

You can add one more rule like this:

```
a[href^="http://www.YOURSITE.com/search/label/TELEVISION"] {
color: #colorcode !important;
background: #colorcode !important;
}
```

Color and background can be of your choice. Make sure you keep the
!important directive intact.